# Whole numbers in BASIC

Tags: integer, int, basic

How can I use Liberty BASIC to find multiples of a number in a range of numbers? For example, between 1 and 10 there are three multiples of number 3: 3, 6, & 9. How would you write a code for that? This is what I've got so far:

```
I = 1
WHILE I <= 10

A = I / 3
IF A = ...
THEN
PRINT I
END IF

I = I + 1
WEND
END
```

Comment: I've now added the line `IF A - INT(A) = 0 THEN` which fixes the problem, but I'm wondering if there's a particular command that would do the job, or an easier way of doing the same thing?

Comment: Liberty Basic doesn't have MOD operator for computing remainders? `I MOD 3 = 0` for any multiple of 3; i.e. dividing any multiple of 3 by 3 will yield no remainder. For example, 96 / 3 = 32, while 96 MOD 3 = 0. Similarly, 95 / 3 = 8.666667, and 95 MOD 3 = 2.

Comment: Awesome, yeah I just found it, that's very useful. Thanks for your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Summary to make this question answered:

```
I = 1
WHILE I <= 10
  IF A MOD 3 = 0 THEN
    PRINT I
  END IF
  I = I + 1
WEND
```